# Burp Suite Proxy Doesn't Forward Any Packets

Tags: linux, proxy, ios, burp-suite

I'm trying to capture data from my iOS device (specifically a troublesome app) and when I configure it to use my laptop on the same wifi as a proxy, I lose all connectivity.

Here's what I did in Burp Suite Free (v1.7.16):

- Turn off intercept (So the button reads `Intercept is off`)
- Under Options, disabled Run on the loopback listener.
- Added a new listener: All interfaces, port 8080. I left the remaining options defaulted.

On iOS:

- Added my laptop's IP address as the host, and port 8080 as the port.

It seems like no traffic *at all* is getting through, whether SSL or not.

Quick edit : The firewall is disabled on my laptop.

Comment: are you sure you have connection between both machines? can you ping between them? which browser are you using? safari? firefox? I guess your browsers config is ok setting correctly proxy ip, port, etc...

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis - Looks like I might've just put the cart before the horse. Can't ping from iOS to laptop (using a "ping" app), nor from laptop to iOS. The router here might be doing a VLAN, though on the same subnet. I'll try again from a different router soon. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah some times wireless APs have "clients isolation" activated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks to be a basic networking problem not a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set Burp proxy (you can leave the loopback alone for other tasks) all interfaces to a port like 8082. Set your iOS device internet options to proxy to your Burp proxy IP/port. Don't forget to install Burp's certificate on your iDevice for SSL. It'd be the same for Android or any other device.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up wireless hotspot on your laptop and connecting to that. I had issues a few years ago that I never properly resolved trying to connect an android app to my laptop running as the server. Worked fine as a hotspot, couldn't sort it on the wifi. I *think* it was some firewall setting somewhere but I never got to the bottom of it.